# Send a message from one class to many others?

Tags: android

I have a class called FlashlightFragment that allows the user to control the flashlight.

The problem is that the user can turn the flashlight on or off from a number of places. Since all changes to the flashlight pass through a class called FlashlightHelper I want to broadcast a message from it that can be received anywhere on my app. I remember there was a way to do this but I cannot remember the name of the feature.

Basically I want to send a message like: "FLASH_ON" from FlashlightHelper and then set listeners on different fragments and activities on my app that can receive this message.

How is this done?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver is what you probably suits you better. remember to unregister it or you will probably leak your fragment and hence the activity

Comment: apart from BroadcastReceiver, you can also use otto or EventBus in order to notify the active fragment or fragments.

Comment: Or an `Interface`  Note that you cannot send to multiple activities since only one activity is running at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't specialize to the specific situation that you face but instead answer the question in general: How to send a message from one class to another (or to many others).

[BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

[Intents and Intent filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

... These are the main methods that will probably be enough for you. Then there are software engineering patterns such as The singleton pattern that will do the trick, but I ll stick to the first to If I were you.